# MySQL. Before update trigger. Can I create record if it doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wallets` (
  `intWalletID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `intAccountID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `doubleSumm` double(16,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`intWalletID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `intAccountID` (`intAccountID`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Table used to record the state of the wallet. To update it, use a simple query like this:

```
UPDATE wallets SET doubleSumm = doubleSumm + @refill_value WHERE intAccountID = @account_id;
```

If record doesn't exist - nothing happens (Affected rows: 0). I'm try solve problem by "BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER", but it doesn't helpful. My non-working trigger:

CREATE DEFINER = `debian-sys-maint`@`%` TRIGGER create_record
BEFORE UPDATE
ON `wallets_test`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE v_account_wallet_id INT UNSIGNED;
SELECT intWalletID, doubleSumm
INTO v_account_wallet_id
FROM wallets
WHERE
intAccountID = NEW.intAccountID;
IF v_account_wallet_id = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO wallets_test (intAccountID) VALUES (NEW.intAccountID);
END IF;
END;

Is it possible in principle? Or I must check existing record in application?

Comment: No, it is not possible in a trigger.

Comment: @Виталий Пастернак - you can also use **INSERT INGNORE .... ON DUPLICATE KEY ...** instead of the UPDATE Statement. This will create or update your row without TRIGGER

Comment: Use  INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/